# How to rename a variable in C?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C and got stuck with one of my requirements. Actually, I want to rename a `char` type variable name in C. Is it possible? if yes how?

```
char A='H';
```

I want to rename variable name from A to B.

```
char A='H';

char B=A;
```

Comment: C or C++? Please choose one

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need this?

Comment: For starters, `char` can only hold a single character, like `'H'`.

Comment: It's a common beginner misconception seeking to name variables in run-time based on user input etc. But doing so is senseless, because variable names exist _solely_ for the benefit of the programmer. Not for the user, not for the compiler. In fact the compiler/linker strips all names out of the program when making the executable, so they no longer exist at that point. Your beginner class/learning material ought to explain that you should create meaningful variable names during development for your own sake, and for the sake of other programmers reading your code. Not for any other purpose.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat also ' and ` are two different things, but might be a typing error

Comment: You can't. What you are doing is creating a new variable B with the same value as A. And as HolyBlackCat pointed out char can only store a single character.

Comment: You can't "rename" variables, but you also don't need to – the situations where you may want to do that can be solved via arrays (which if you haven't covered already you'll soon learn about), or dictionaries (conceptually like arrays that can be indexed with anything, not just integers, a bit more complicated to set up from scratch).

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are only used in source code.  To rename the variable `A`, just modify the source code and use `B` wherever you used `A` to refer to this object:

```
char B[] = "Hello";
```

Also note that `` char A='hello`; `` is meaningless in C because the backquote is an invalid character, strings are delimited by double quotes `"` and `char` defines a character, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

It will not rename the variable, but it will replace all of occurrences of `A` with `B`.

```
#define B A

int main(void)
{
    char A[] = "I am A";
    printf("'%s'\n", B);
}
```